# Extract Month and Day from Date in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to extract month and day from Date as shown below

```
> asd <- data.frame(a = c('2020-02-15', '2020-03-16'))
> asd
           a
1 2020-02-15
2 2020-03-16
```

Expected output

```
> asd
           a    b
1 2020-02-15   Feb-15
2 2020-03-16   Mar-16
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert to `Date` class and `format` it

```
asd <- transform(asd, b = format(as.Date(a), '%b-%d'))
asd
           a      b
1 2020-02-15 Feb-15
2 2020-03-16 Mar-16
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option using `strftime`:

```
asd$b <- strftime(asd$a, '%b-%d')
```

**Output**

```
           a      b
1 2020-02-15 Feb-15
2 2020-03-16 Mar-16
```

Or we could do the same using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

asd %>% 
  mutate(b = strftime(a, '%b-%d'))
```